# multiple ng-repeat with ng-if expression

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

i have installments lists of banks comes with json and i want to repeat the list that whetever bank support installment count or not on payment page. list must be count up to 9 starting from 2.

this is the json (includes only first bank)

```
    [{
      "Installments": [{
        "InstallmentId": 9,
        "InstCount": 2,
        "InstRate": 0,
        "BankId": 1,
        "Info": false
      }, {
        "InstallmentId": 10,
        "InstCount": 3,
        "InstRate": 0,
        "BankId": 1,
        "Info": false
      }, {
        "InstallmentId": 11,
        "InstCount": 4,
        "InstRate": 7.30,
        "BankId": 1,
        "Info": false
      }, {
        "InstallmentId": 12,
        "InstCount": 5,
        "InstRate": 0,
        "BankId": 1,
        "Info": false
      }, {
        "InstallmentId": 13,
        "InstCount": 7,
        "InstRate": 4.50,
        "BankId": 1,
        "Info": false
      }, {
        "InstallmentId": 14,
        "InstCount": 9,
        "InstRate": 11.28,
        "BankId": 1,
        "Info": false
      }],
      "BankId": 1,
      "BankName": "Garanti",
      "IsInstallments": false,
      "BankLogo": "img/bank/cards-01.png"
    }, {
      "Installments": [...],
      "BankId": 2,
      "BankName": "Advantage",
      "IsInstallments": false,
      "BankLogo": "img/bank/cards-05.png"
    }, {
      "Installments": [...],
      "BankId": 3,
      "BankName": "Finansbank",
      "IsInstallments": false,
      "BankLogo": "img/bank/cards-03.png"
    }]
```

this is the html markup:

```
    <div id="installments" 
    class="{{bankValue !== '' ? 'inactive' : '' }}">
      <div class="row m0 row-paddless">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2" 
        ng-repeat="bank in json" >
          <section data-bank-id="{{bank.BankId}}" 
          class="bank {{bankValue == bank.BankId ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}">
            <div style="background-image: url('{{bank.BankLogo}}');" class="img-holder"></div>
            <ul>

              <li ng-repeat-start="i in [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"  
              ng-if="bank.Installments[i-2].InstCount !== i || bank.Installments[i-2].InstCount == undefined">
                <p>{{i}} TAKSİT</p>
                <p>disabled</p>
                <p><small>disabled</small></p>
              </li>
              <li ng-repeat-end="i in [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" 
              ng-click="clickLi(ins, bank)" 
              ng-if="bank.Installments[i-2].InstCount == i" class="{{installmentValue == bank.Installments[i-2].InstCount ? 'active' : '' }} {{bank.Installments[i-2].InstRate == 0 ? 'special' : '' }}">
                <p>{{bank.Installments[i-2].InstCount}} TAKSİT</p>
                <p><span itemprop="price" class="price-value" ng-init="newPrice = price + (price * bank.Installments[i-2].InstRate / 100)"> {{ newPrice | number:2 }} TL</span></p>
                <p ng-init="installedPrice = ((price + (price * bank.Installments[i-2].InstRate / 100)) / bank.Installments[i-2].InstCount)"><span><small>  {{ installedPrice | number:2 }} TL X {{bank.Installments[i-2].InstCount}} ay</small></span></p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </section><!-- "bank" -->
        </div><!-- "col-xs-4 col-sm-2" -->
      </div><!-- "row" -->
    </div><!-- installments -->
```

this is what i get (screenshot):
http://aslanbakan.com/down/bank-error.PNG

this is what i want to achive (screenshot):
http://aslanbakan.com/down/bank-achive.PNG

I don't know where i did the mistake.

Comment: The links to the screenshots are not OK. Also, it would be very helpful if you could provide a minimal working example (JSFiddle, JS Bin etc.)

Comment: fixed the ss. and added the pen.. 
[codepen link](http://codepen.io/Aslanbakan/pen/PqKGQY)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want to display only those banks that have an Installment.

You checked for

```
bank.Installments[i-2].InstCount == undefined
```

But you need to check the typeof attribute equals undefined, like this:

```
typeof bank.Installments[i-1].InstCount === 'undefined'
```

Updated the pen you provided: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dozpBE

Comment: no, i actually want to show all items whetever installment exist or not. 
If installment doesn't exist, i want to show disabled text on that item. just like on 'want to achieve' screenshot.

Comment: you should use ng-class instead of ng-if for that case.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the problem ... see this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNEBpK

Comment: bank serves all ratios except 6 and 8 count installment. i want to show "disabled" text in 6th and 8th li tag on ul list. But for loop turns disabled after 6th and up. 
It's disabled in 7th and 9th installment too on this pen. But bank supports installment ratios for 7 and 9 installment.